# How to create a process for each vowel?

Tags: c, command-line

I am new at Processes. I read a lot but I didn't really understand how it works. I try to make a process for each vowel in a char string. I have to delete all vowels from that string. I know that I have to use fork, but I don't know how. I tried to write the code, but what I receive was Core Dumped.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char sir[100];

int vocal(char x)  
{

  if(x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u' || x=='A'|| 
  x=='E' || x=='I' || x=='O' || x=='U')
return 1;
return 0;

}
int main(){

printf("Read the text: \n");
read(1,sir,100); // file descriptor is 1;
pid_t a_Process;

for(int i=0;i<strlen(sir);i++)
{

  if(vocal(sir[i])==1)
    {
    a_Process=fork();
    for(int j=i;j<strlen(sir)-1;i++)
        sir[j]=sir[j+1];
}               

 }
 printf("%s",sir);
  return 0;
}
```

I didn't understand how the child process and everything goes. Thank you very much!

Comment: C or C++?  They are different languages, with different answers.

Comment: Sorry C, I mistook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char sir[100];

int vocal(char x)
{
    if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' ||
        x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, pid_status;

    printf("Read the text: \n");
    // read(1,sir,100); // file descriptor is 1;
    fgets(sir, 100, stdin);

    pid_t a_Process;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(sir); i++)
    {
        if (vocal(sir[i]) == 1)
        {
            printf("detected a vowel\n");

            a_Process = fork();
            if (a_Process == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't fork a process.\n");
                return 1;
            }

            if (a_Process)
            {
                printf("Starting a new child .... \n");
                for (j = i; j < strlen(sir) - 1; j++)
                    sir[j] = sir[j + 1];
            }

            // The following statement is needed such that
            // child process starts one after the other.
            if (waitpid(a_Process, &pid_status, 0) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error waiting for child process.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", sir);
    return 0;
}
```